# How to add a text to navigation bar on a duplicate page

Tags: css, navigation

I was wondering if someone can help me out on how to add a text to the top navigation bar for my company's website. 
The page is a duplicate and I removed the menu.

Any assistance, help or advice is much appreciated.

Thanks,
C

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: @CarlaCayton It is better if you showed your HTML code related to the top navigation bar and ask from StackOverflow community how to place the text in the right position. Otherwise, people would wander how to help you.